# MYSQL C Connector

Tags: mysql, c, linux

I have a C process that is rapidly writing to a mysql database ~10 times per second. This process uses the MySql C Connector.

After about 2 minutes of running, the process hangs and in system monitor shows

```
 "futex_wait_queue_me"
```

, and also

```
"Can't initialized threads: error 11"
```

is printed to console, I assume by the C connector library(since I do not print this). Following that write, connections to mysql fail with

```
"MySQL server has gone away".
```

What could be causing this? I am only writing from 1 thread.

fyi, I am using the library as so. mutex lock and unlock are there for future as i will be multithreading the logging. The logging events in actual app will be much less frequent, but I am trying to stress it as much as possible in this particular test.

```
//pseudocode:
while(1)
    mutexlock
    connect();
    mysql_query();
    disconnect();
    sleep(100ms);
    mutexunlock


A better solution, maybe not the best
    connect();
    while(1)
        mutexlock

        if error on mysql_query();
            disconnect();
            connect();
        sleep(100ms);
        mutexunlock



//connect/disconnect functions
int DBConnector::connect()
{
    if(DBConnector::m_isConnected) return 0;//already connected...
    if(!mutexInitialized)
    {
        pthread_mutex_init(&DBLock, 0);
    }
    if(mysql_library_init(0, NULL, NULL))
    {
        LoggingUtil::logError("DBConnector.DB_connect [DB library init error] " + string(mysql_error(&DBConnector::m_SQLHandle)));
        DBConnector::m_isConnected = false;
        return -1;
    }

    if((mysql_init(&m_SQLHandle)) == NULL)
    {      
        LoggingUtil::logError("DBConnector.DB_connect [DB mysql init error] " + string(mysql_error(&DBConnector::m_SQLHandle)));
        DBConnector::m_isConnected = false;
        return -1;
    }

   if((mysql_real_connect(&DBConnector::m_SQLHandle, host.c_str(), user.c_str(), pw.c_str(), db.c_str(), port, socket.c_str(), client_flags)) == NULL)
   {
       LoggingUtil::logError("DBConnector.DB_connect [DB Connect error] " + string(mysql_error(&DBConnector::m_SQLHandle)));
       DBConnector::m_isConnected = false;
       return -1;
   }   

    DBConnector::m_isConnected = true;
    return 0;
}
int DBConnector::disconnect()
{
    DBConnector::m_isConnected = false;
    mysql_close(&DBConnector::m_SQLHandle);

    mysql_library_end();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why you are using `mutex` when the `mysql` handles races and other same issues itself ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to not call

```
mysql_library_init(0, NULL, NULL);
```

and

```
mysql_library_end();
```

at each connection attempt.

Also your second idea of not reconnecting at every mysql-access is much better as establishing a connection will always take some time/resource. For nothing in your case.

**After a query has failed, you don't need to re-connect to the database.**

Comment: mysql connections timeout after a while and so I just reconnect on error.